# How can I determine the price for buying/hiring monsters?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pricing, followers-and-hirelings

I want the players in my compaign have the ability to "buy" monsters in any Bestiary as mercenary to fight for them. But I can't figure out how to determine the price for it.

I had looked up on the "Recruit" rules, but it's all about recruiting "non-combat" individuals such as cooks or doctors. I had checked the "Leadership" feat too, but it also didn't mention anything related to the "price" of the hiring.

I believe it's only resonable that the price is proportional to the CR of the monster, but I can't figure the right "formula" for it.

Is there a price for buying or hiring a monster this way? Where can I find those pricing rules, if they exist?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! We don't field product recommendation requests here ("recommend me a book that does X"), so I have reworded the question to instead straightforwardly ask what the rules are, since this will get you the information you're seeking but in a way that works better on our site. Answerers may then indicate whether they exist in official material, and if not, they may elect to mention third party material or recommend specific guidelines that have worked for them.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Animals & Animal Gear](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/animals-animal-gear/) is the closest thing I'm aware of in the original rules. It might not be suitable for all settings, and it far short of the "entire bestiary".

Please note that the Bestiary includes lot of sapient species and even humanoid opponents. Making the entire thing available might run into some moral issues for the party for some options, depending on the terms of the sale/mercenary contract.

Comment: Thanks! I'll put all its relative CR and price into some regression calculater and see if I could find any rules in it.

Comment: I'd strongly advise to consider that minimum price. And your *r* will be... unkind. Good luck, though!

Comment: As someone who has inquired about beast sales in my own game, be careful. The price of animals is not based on power. For example, a dire tiger is merely ~1000g. This is affordable early and trained, is very dangerous. Or, without training, you can simply kill it, and a specialized wizard of 3rd level, can animate this 14 HD tiger, as an undead, for simply an extra 500g. So, for less than a +1 weapon, a necromancer can get a 14HD undead with 73hp, 3 attacks @ +18 to hit. With prep and a bit of extra gold, (still less than 2k) you can make it bloody, for an extra 28hp and the undying trait.